# ondragover event to change colors

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

This is simple code that should simply change the boarder and background colors of the target divs when they are hovered over. The colors should change depending on what is being dragged, which it should determine `ondragstart`. However nothing happens, in fact my cursor is the not allowed thing. (Circle with the line through it) So what's the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Play four-in-a-Row</title>
    <meta charset=ütf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<div class="container-fluid">
<body onload="boardSetup()">
    <div id="header" >
    <h1 id = "Main">Four-in-a-Row</h1>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div  id = "drop">
        <div class="row">
        <div class = "col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" data-toggle="tooltip" title = "Column 1" ondragover = "dragOver(event)" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" data-toggle="tooltip" title = "Column 2" ondragover = "dragOver(event)"></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" data-toggle="tooltip" title = "Column 3" ondragover = "dragOver(event)"></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" data-toggle="tooltip" title = "Column 4" ondragover = "dragOver(event)"></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" data-toggle="tooltip" title = "Column 5" ondragover = "dragOver(event)"></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" data-toggle="tooltip" title = "Column 6" ondragover = "dragOver(event)"></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" data-toggle="tooltip" title = "Column 7" ondragover = "dragOver(event)"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id="board" >
        <div class="row">
            <div class = "col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" ></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class = "col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" ></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class = "col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" ></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class = "col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" ></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class = "col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" ></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class = "col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" ></div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
    <div  class= "piece">
            <img src= "player_1.png" alt= "Player 1 piece" height = 15% width = 15% id = "player1" data-toggle="tooltip" title = "Player one's piece" class ="player1 piece" draggable= "true" ondragstart ="dragStart(event)" > </img>
            <img src= "player_2.png" alt= "Player 2 piece" height = 15% width = 15% id = "player2" data-toggle="tooltip" title = "Player two's piece" class = "player2 piece" draggable= "true" ondragstart ="dragStart(event)"> </img>         
    </div>
    <script>
    var map;
    var dragged = 0;
        function boardSetup(){
            var board=document.getElementsByClassName("square");
            var blank = "<img src = blank.png alt= blank class = blank>";
            for(var x = 0; x < board.length; x++){
                board[x].innerHTML(blank)
            }
            
            document.getElementById("board").innerHTML=board;
            var temp2 = document.getElementsByClassName("blank");
            for(var z in temp2){
                temp2[z].className += " piece";
            }
        }
        
        function gameStart(){
        }
        
        
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();     
        });
        
        function dragStart(event) {
            event.dataTransfer.setData("text", event.target.id);
            if(event.target.id == "player1")
                dragged = 1;
            else if(event.target.id){
                dragged = 2;
            }
        }
        
        function dragOver(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            if(draaged = 1){
                event.target.style.border = "blue";
                event.target.style.background-color = "#59F2F7";    
            }else if(draaged = 2){
                event.target.style.border-clolor = "red";
                event.target.style.background-color = " #F75D59";
            }
        }
        
        
</script>
<input type="button" onclick="boardSetup()" value="Reset" class="btn btn-danger btn-block" > </input>
</div>
</body>

<footer>
    <hr>
    <a href="../index.html">&lt;- Back to launch page</a>
    <hr>
    <p style= "text-align: right"> done by <br>Justin Michel <br> u14369852</p>
    <hr>
</footer>
```

Comment: Do you use console for debuigging?

event.target.style.border-clolor = "red"; // camel cased and misspel
event.target.style.background-color = "#59F2F7"; // should be camelcased

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following statements are not valid Javascript code. They are interpreted as substruction expressions followed by an attempt to assign a value to an expression which doesn't make sense. You'll have to replace following lines with the corresponding camelCase variants:

- `event.target.style.background-color = "#59F2F7";`
- `event.target.style.border-clolor = "red";`
- `event.target.style.background-color = " #F75D59";`

replace with:

`event.target.style.backgroundColor = "#59F2F7";`

And so forth. (And there is no such thing as `clolor`)

Another error is `board[x].innerHTML(blank)` - `innerHTML` is not a function. It is a property and here is link to documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

You can spot both of these errors if you open console. The console even gives you link to jump to the offending line in the code, which makes debugging easy. It might not be the full solution, but fixing those is necessary for your code to work. The referenced stylesheet is not provided with the question so it is not possible to fully answer your question (e.g. you "blocked" cursor might be caused by some style definition in your stylesheet).

There are more problems with the code you posted, even though might not be related directly to the drag event, but still worth raising.

`img` element is a void (empty) element: *In HTML, using a closing tag on an empty element is usually invalid*. It is not closed with  but with *"/>"* on the opening tag. Same goes for `input` element. Here is link to documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Empty_element

`body` tag is not supposed to be nested inside `div`, even if it works it's not a good practice. https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-body-element